# For $n \ge 20$, there are at least $0.6 \cdot \frac{2^n}{n}$ primes in $\left[2^{n-1},2^n - 1\right]$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

From the prime number theorem, one can deduce the following inequality:

> For $x \ge 355991$, if $\pi(x) = \left|\{p \le x:p \text{ is prime}\}\right|$
>   then we have 
>   $$\frac{x}{\ln(x)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right) < \pi(x) <
>  \frac{x}{\ln(x)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln(x)}+\frac{2.51}{(\ln(x))^2}\right)$$

Form here I have to deduce that for $n \ge 20$ one has that there are at least $0.6 \cdot \frac{2^n}{n}$ primes in $\left[2^{n-1},2^n - 1\right]$.

**My try**

Observation: $\pi(2^n -1) = \pi(2^n)$ since $2^n$ is not prime.

So the number of primes in $\left[2^{n-1},2^n - 1\right]$ is given by $\pi\left(2^n\right)-\pi\left(2^{n-1}\right)$.

We have:

$$\pi\left(2^{n-1}\right) <\frac{2^{n-1}}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}+\frac{2.51}{\left(\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)\right)^2}\right) \implies \\
-\frac{2^{n-1}}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}+\frac{2.51}{\left(\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)\right)^2}\right) < -\pi\left(2^{n-1}\right) $$

$$\frac{2^n}{\ln\left(2^n\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2^n\right)}\right) < \pi\left(2^n\right)$$

adding up these two:

$$\frac{2^n}{\ln\left(2^n\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2^n\right)}\right) - \frac{2^{n-1}}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}+\frac{2.51}{\left(\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)\right)^2}\right) < \pi\left(2^n\right) - \pi\left(2^{n-1}\right)$$

At this point I could do various simplifications but I cannot find the right approximation. Any ideas?

**Related:**

[How many all prime numbers p with length of bits of p = 1024 bits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263588/how-many-all-prime-numbers-p-with-length-of-bits-of-p-1024-bits)

**Other sources:**

This [slides](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hmaji/teaching/Fall%202018/lectures/11.pdf) provide a rough estimation.

[Here](http://mathscinotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/shortage.pdf) there seems to be an accurate deduction referenced (see section 4)

In particular, they refer to corollary 3 in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807) which reads:

> For $x \ge 20.5$, $$\frac{3 \cdot x}{5 \cdot \log(x)} < \pi(2x) - \pi(x)$$

I would still thank he person with the patience to put everything together and give a well-reasoned answer.

Comment: In the estimation in the yellow box you have x/lnx in the upper bound, but when you plug in $2^{n-1}$, you write 1/ln($2^{n-1}$).

Comment: @Student7 is fixed now, thank you

Comment: Using $\ln(2^n) = n \ln(2)$ etc. and factoring out $\frac{2^n}{n}$ does not help? Then we have a sum which we have to bound by $0.6$.

Comment: @Stockfish not really, this is the kind of simplification i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it:
$$\frac{2^n}{\ln\left(2^n\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2^n\right)}\right) - \frac{2^{n-1}}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)}+\frac{2.51}{\left(\ln\left(2^{n-1}\right)\right)^2}\right)=\\
\frac{2^n}{n}\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{\ln2}}+
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n(\ln2)^2}}-\color{red}{\frac{n}{2(n-1)\ln{2}}}-
\color{blue}{\frac{n}{2(n-1)^2(\ln{2})^2}}-
\frac{n\cdot2.51}{2(n-1)^3(\ln{2})^3}\right)=\\
\frac{2^n}{n}\left(\color{red}{\frac{n-2}{(n-1)\ln{4}}}+
\color{blue}{\frac{n^2-4n+2}{2(n-1)^2 n(\ln{2})^2}}-
\frac{n\cdot2.51}{2(n-1)^3(\ln{2})^3}\right)=\\
\frac{2^n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\ln{4}}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+
\frac{1}{n\ln{2}}\left(1-\frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2}\right)-
\frac{n\cdot 2.51}{(n-1)^3(\ln{2})^2}\right)>...$$
Now, it is not too difficult (checking 1st derivative and monotonicity) [to show that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%5Cfrac%7B2n-1%7D%7B(n-1)%5E2%7D)
$$1-\frac{2n-1}{(n-1)^2}>\frac{1}{2}, \forall n\geq6$$
[and](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%5Ccdot%202.51%7D%7B(n-1)%5E3(%5Cln%7B2%7D)%5E2%7D)
$$-\frac{n^2\cdot 2.51}{(n-1)^3(\ln{2})^2} > -\frac{1}{2}, \forall n\geq14$$
thus
$$...>\frac{2^n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\ln{4}}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+
\frac{1}{2n\ln{2}}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\\
\frac{2^n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\ln{4}}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+
\frac{1}{2n}\left(\frac{1}{\ln{2}}-1\right)\right)>\\
\frac{2^n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\ln{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-1}+
\frac{0.4426}{2n}\right) > ...$$
and again, [checking 1st derivative and monotonicity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fln(4))*(1-1%2F(n-1)%2B%200.4426%2F(2n))) we have 
$$\frac{1}{\ln{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-1}+
\frac{0.4426}{2n}\right)>0.6, \forall n\geq6$$
thus, finally
$$...> 0.6 \frac{2^n}{n}$$

It is also worth mentioning [this paper](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram24.pdf), Ramanujan's proof of Bertrand’s postulate.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, i don't have the time now to check but i'm sure other readers will give a better feedback with their votes.