# $π(x+y) - π(x) ≤ c·y/\ln(y)$ for some constant $c$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures

Thinking about the prime number theorem, I wondered whether it is known that there is some constant $c$ such that $π(x+y) ≤ π(x) + c·y/\ln(y)$ for every integers $x,y > 1$. I read that experts believe $π(x+y) ≤ π(x) + π(y)$ fails for some $y$, since [it fails for $y = 3159$ if the k-tuple conjecture holds](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/the-quest-for-narrow-admissible-tuples), but it is just barely false, so I am curious if it is known to be true if the inequality is relaxed by a constant factor. If so, is it also known that $π(x+y) ≤ π(x) + π(y) + c·\!\sqrt{y}·\ln(y)$ for some constant $c$? I simply do not know how to search for such conjectures, and neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) nor [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html) seem to state any results that would affirm or refute these two conjectures easily, so any references would be appreciated!

(After a year, I've now posted it [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/370905/50073).)

Comment: (1) I think you should use $C$ instead of $c$. (2) It is known (with $c=2$). A standard proof uses sieve theory. See, for example, montgomery and vaughan multiplicative number theory chapter 3.2. (3) I don't know about the $C\sqrt{y}\ln(y)$ bound.

Comment: @mathworker21: Thanks! Can you post an answer with what you know?

Comment: This is quite equivalent to the main conjectures on the prime gap, search about Cramer's conjecture and see what you get from the random model for the primes.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) Wikipedia article mentiones <<Hoheisel (1930) was the first to show that there exists a constant $θ < 1$ such that $
{\displaystyle \pi (x+x^{\theta })-\pi (x)\sim {\frac {x^{\theta }}{\log(x)}}{\text{ as }}x\to \infty}$>>

Comment: @reuns: Sorry I can't see why. Cramer's stronger conjecture is not supported by more accurate heuristics, and the weaker one only seems to give a lower bound on the number of primes in $[x+1..x+y]$, whereas what I asked for was an upper bound.

Comment: @rtybase: Thanks. Am I correct to say that Hoheisel's result can be used to prove a special case of my first conjecture, namely for $x^θ ≤ y ≤ x^k$ where $k$ is any fixed constant? What about the other cases, when $y$ is small or large relative to $x$?

Comment: @user21820 it's a theorem, so yes you can use it, but more for $x<y\leq  x+x^{\theta}$. It is also worth mentioning [this paper](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram24.pdf) of Ramanujan, imposing a possible lower limit.

Comment: You will also find a few useful and interesting resources [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067450/for-n-ge-20-there-are-at-least-0-6-cdot-frac2nn-primes-in-left2/)

Comment: @rtybase: No, I extended to $y ≤ x^k$ for fixed $k$ by simply concatenating the ranges: Let $c$ be such that $π(x+x^θ) - π(x)$ $≤ c·x^θ/\ln(x)$ for every $x$. Then for any $y ≤ x^k$ we have $π(x+y) - π(x)$ $≤ \sum_{i=0}^{y/x^θ} ( π(x+x^θ·(i+1)) - π(x+x^θ·i) )$ $≤ \sum_{i=0}^{y/x^θ} ( c·x^θ/\ln(x+x^θ·i) )$ $≤ (y/x^θ+1)·c·x^θ/\ln(x)$ $≤ c·(y+x^θ)·k/\ln(y)$ $≤ 2c·k·y/\ln(y)$. And I saw the inequality you linked to, but I don't think it helps here.

Comment: Maybe migrate to MathOverflow?

Comment: @rtybase: Did you get my previous messages? Or did you find anything new since the last time?

Comment: @user21820 yes, I did, but not much to share :( ... apart from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.02366.pdf) paper.

Comment: @rtybase: Ooh that's nice, at least something even more than what you told me the last time. Thanks! =)

Comment: Using Dusart's bounds of $x/(-1+\log x)<\pi(x)\le x/(-1.1+\log x)$ it suffices to show that $\frac{\ln\left(y\right)}{y}\cdot\left(\frac{x+y}{\ln\left(x+y\right)-1.1}-\frac{x}{\ln\left(x\right)-1}\right)\le c$ and calculus with respect to $x$ then $y$ shows that $c<2$.

Comment: I retract what I said and hence my answer, as the LHS of the inequality in my comment above actually diverges, albeit *very* slowly. So I think this problem is very non-trivial. Note that a necessary condition of your inequality is that there exists a constant $M_k$ such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{\log x}x\int_k^{k+x}\frac{dt}{\log t}+M_k\frac{(k+x)\log x}x\exp\left(-\frac{\log(k+x)^{3/5}}{5\log(\log(k+x))^{1/5}}\right)\right]$$ is finite for all integers $k>1$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Ah okay. Well luckily I hadn't started thinking about your comment or answer yet! =D